# Strange behavior with Spring CGlib autowairing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, cglib

I am working with `Spring MVC` application.

I want to create new event:

> fill data at page > controller handle this info > saving new event to DB

I have already created DAO layer and repository layer. But at some places, it  behaves very strangely. I have created Java configuration for all repositories in the same way.

Here is ***Repositories Configuration*** snippet:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "net.lelyak.edu.repository", "net.lelyak.edu.service" })
@Import({ DatabaseDAOConfiguration.class })
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private EventDAO eventDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TicketDAO ticketDAO;

    @Autowired
    private AuditoriumDAO auditoriumDAO;

    @Bean
    public AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository() {
        AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository = new AuditoriumRepository();
        auditoriumRepository.setDao(auditoriumDAO);
        return auditoriumRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public EventRepository eventRepository() {
        EventRepository eventRepository = new EventRepository();
        eventRepository.setDao(eventDAO);
        return eventRepository;
    }
```

I have faced strange behavior at the controller level.

Here is controller code snippet:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("events")
public class EventsController {

    @Autowired
    private AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEvent(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
       Event newEvent = new Event();
       // get auditorium id from request
       String auditoryIdString = allRequestParams.get("auditorium");
       Long auditoryId = Long.parseLong(auditoryIdString);
       Auditorium auditorium = auditoriumRepository.getById(auditoryId);
       newEvent.setAuditorium(auditorium);
```

***AuditoriumRepository*** is auto-wired fine.
Here is snippet from debug view:

[image]

but ***EventRepository*** isn't:

[image]

Configuration is the same for both. One repository is auto-wired fine, second fails. I am newly at Spring. I can't get a clue why does this happen?

Here is snippet of code from ***EventRepository***:

```
public class EventRepository extends BaseRepository<Event, EventDAO> {

    @Autowired
    private AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository;

    @Override
    public int put(Event entity) {
        auditoriumRepository.put(entity.getAuditorium());
        return super.put(entity);
    }
```

***AuditoriumRepository*** code snippet:

```
public class AuditoriumRepository extends BaseRepository<Auditorium, AuditoriumDAO> {

    @Override
    public Auditorium preSave(Auditorium entity) {
        return entity;
    }
```

For saving new event to DB I have to use exactly ***EventRepository***. It fails, of course, with following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at net.lelyak.edu.repository.BaseRepository.put(BaseRepository.java:23) 
at net.lelyak.edu.repository.EventRepository.put(EventRepository.java:20) 
at net.lelyak.edu.repository.EventRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5de8d2a5.invoke() 
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

I am using spring `4.2.4.RELEASE` on Windows 10.

**UPDATE:**

***BaseRepository*** code snippet:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, E extends BaseDAO<T>> {    
    private E dao;

    public E getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(E dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public int put(T entity) {
        return dao.save(preSave(entity));
    }
```

I can't understand why with the same configuration and repository structure. One instance is auto-wired by Spring fine, but the second one fails. How to find the root of this problem? And some solution.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have tried recommended solution, and added next setter to ***EventRepository***:

```
public void setAuditoriumRepository(AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository) {
    System.out.println("EventRepository.setAuditoriumRepository");
    this.auditoriumRepository = auditoriumRepository;
}
```

As log message show this setter is executed. But keep failing for the same reason.

***How to solve this issue?***

Comment: The exception is thrown from BaseRepository.put(). What's in this method. Post the relevant code.

Comment: Are these spring-data repositories or named as repositories, but they are custom Repo ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri They are not Spring Data repository. They are custom Repository. For combining logic between model entity and DAO layer. And my question is - why at some case repository bean are autowired, but another one isn't. Configuration for both are the same.

Comment: @JBNizet I have update question with full project source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw your code and the problem is not related to Spring and autowiring process. The problem is in your `save` method in BaseDAO class:

```
@Override
public Integer save(ENTITY entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        insert(entity);
    } else {
        update(entity);
    }
    return null;
}
```

if you change the metod to return newly inserted/updated entity id it will work fine.

try to hardcode it just for test :

```
@Override
public Integer save(ENTITY entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        insert(entity);
    } else {
        update(entity);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and the problem is raised when you return `null` from `save` method then you are doing assignment in the `EventsController` class which is:

`int eventId = eventRepository.put(newEvent); //this is null` and throws `NullPointerException` because you are trying to assign `null` to primitive variable.

Comment: Good shot! Can you leave some feedback about weak places for this project? Just few words. It will be very helpful.

Comment: actually I can write several words for your project but this is not related to your question. I checkout the code from github and actually I'm impressed at all. I have few suggestions about ...i think your code looks like little bit older.. I mean remove all xml configuration files, check out spring xml less config, you can do everything in pure java. also i think its a little overhead to do Dao, Repository etc., checkout Spring Data project, it will reduce a lot boilerplate code and do a lot of things more easily. if you want additional advices just ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject the dependencies yourself in the Java ***@Configuration*** class. Update your EventRepository so that it has a setter method for the AuditoriumRepository dependency as follows

```
public class EventRepository extends BaseRepository<Event, EventDAO> {

    private AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository;

    @Override
    public int put(Event entity) {
        auditoriumRepository.put(entity.getAuditorium());
        return super.put(entity);
    }

    public void setAuditoriumRepository(AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository){
        this.auditoriumRepository=auditoriumRepository;
    } 
}
```

In your ***ApplicationConfiguration*** update as follow:

```
        @Bean
        public EventRepository eventRepository() {
            EventRepository eventRepository = new EventRepository();
            eventRepository.setDao(eventDAO);
            eventRepository.setAuditoriumRepository(auditoriumRepository());
            return eventRepository;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception is because `auditoriumRepository` is not set in the `eventRepository` bean.

So while creating the `EventRepository` bean in `ApplicationConfiguration.java`, we need to set `auditoriumRepository` as well.

For this I have updated `ApplicationConfiguration` as below:

```
public EventRepository eventRepository() {
    EventRepository eventRepository = new EventRepository();
    eventRepository.setDao(eventDAO);
    eventRepository.setAuditoriumRepository(auditoriumRepository());
    return eventRepository;
}
```

and added setter for `auditoriumRepository` in the `EventRepository` class

```
public AuditoriumRepository getAuditoriumRepository() {
    return auditoriumRepository;
}

public void setAuditoriumRepository(AuditoriumRepository auditoriumRepository) {
    this.auditoriumRepository = auditoriumRepository;
}
```

This will ensure that the NPE you are seeing will be resolved.

But subsequently we will still get the NPE at a different point now and i.e., at `BaseDAO` class. The `save` method is returning a null object and that is causing this NPE.

To resolve this, I have updated the `save` method of `BaseDAO` to return a dummy value of `1`. You may want to return an appropriate value as per you application needs.

```
public Integer save(ENTITY entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        insert(entity);
    } else {
        update(entity);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

With these changes, we will able to save the event and proceed to the next screen.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But your answer is combination of two answers, which have mentioned before.

Comment: @nazar_art My bad. I did see the answer related to `eventRepository.setAuditoriumRepository(auditoriumRepository());` but should have noticed that even the second NPE related to `save` method of `BaseDAO` has been answered.